# Android app - display terminal view

Tags: android, user-interface

I was hoping someone could help me with a basic task regarding making an extremely basic android gui.

I have an app to which i want to print some data via `toString()`. I want to display this in a console type view with it printing / refreshing every 10 seconds or so. Currently i am printing to the `Log.e` command but am unsure what control i need to add for it to be a console output view.

I guess i could just add a text box and keep adding new lines but ideally a console / command line output is what i desire.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like console in Android. You can use logcat as you are using right now or you can use some TextView to show your output.

I think you could use `TextView` in `ScrollView` for this with appending new lines to previous text with xml layout like

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/consoleText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ScrollView>
```

and then adding:

```
String previousString = textView.getText().toString();
String nextString = previousString + "\n" + nextLine;
textView.setText(nextString);
```